# Sqlite throws "invalid column title" on existing title

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I'm trying to something that I thought should be quite simple and straight forward. I'm trying to load some data from a Sqlite database on android that I created my self. The only problem is that I get this error:

```
W/MainActivity: onCreate started
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/NotificationDbHelper: Column in cursor named: _id
W/NotificationDbHelper: Column in cursor named: title
W/NotificationDbHelper: Column in cursor named: additional
W/NotificationDbHelper: Column in cursor named: icon
W/MainActivity: onCreate ended
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

              [ 10-04 09:04:07.090  4272: 4272 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad17b6a0, tid 4272
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: dk.simwir.lockscreennotifications, PID: 4272
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column title
                  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
                  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
                  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
                  at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
                  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
                  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
                  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

When trying to load in data from the table. The main error seams to be: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column title`. It claims that the column is invalid, but as you can see in log output I have created it appears to be there: `W/NotificationDbHelper: Column in cursor named: title`. And I have accessed the database from the android adb and also confirmed it to exist:

[image: Table schema]

When researching the problem the main 'fix' I found was the that I needed to add it to a projection map, but I tried that, but it still didn't fix it.

The error does not seem to happen directly in my code, but on a background thread, so the log output makes it hard to pinpoint the error. But the information from the database is loaded in this code:

```
Cursor cursor = notificationDbHelper.getAllActiveNotifications();
    if(cursor == null){
        Log.e(TAG, "Cursor returned null");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cursor_null_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }else if (cursor.getCount()==0){
        Log.e(TAG, "Cursor returned empty");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_active_notifications, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }else{
        String[] fromColumns = {ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_TITLE, ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ADDITIONAL_TEXT};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.notification_title, R.id.notification_additional_text};

        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.id.simple_notification, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        notificationList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }
```

The `getAllActiveNotifications` function, which interacts with the database looks like this:

```
public Cursor getAllActiveNotifications(){
    HashMap<String, String> myProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    myProjectionMap.put(ActiveNotificationEntry._ID, ActiveNotificationEntry._ID);
    myProjectionMap.put(ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_TITLE, ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_TITLE);
    myProjectionMap.put(ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ADDITIONAL_TEXT, ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ADDITIONAL_TEXT);
    myProjectionMap.put(ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ICON, ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ICON);

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(ActiveNotificationEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(myProjectionMap);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db,CURSOR_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor!=null){
        for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){
            Log.w("NotificationDbHelper", "Column in cursor named: " + cursor.getColumnName(i));
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }else {
        Log.e("NotificationDbHelper", "Cursor returned null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

The cursor colums array contains this:

```
public static final String[] CURSOR_COLUMNS = new String[]{
        ActiveNotificationEntry._ID,
        ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_TITLE,
        ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ADDITIONAL_TEXT,
        ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ICON};
```

The table is created in the same file as the getActiveNotification(). That file extends SQLiteOpenHelper, and has this on create:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(NotificationContract.SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}
```

The SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES constant referenced here is:

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + ActiveNotificationEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                ActiveNotificationEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" + COMMA_SEP +
                ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ICON + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                ActiveNotificationEntry.COLUM_NAME_ADDITIONAL_TEXT + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
```

I have tried a simple database.query instead of the QueryBuilder, but with the same result:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(ActiveNotificationEntry.TABLE_NAME, CURSOR_COLUMNS,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

Even though the error message says it was in a "doInBackground()" There shouldn't be any asynkTasks active at this time.

I have collected all the files i think are relevant in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/simwir/33c222a1159de56a3395d46c5e7febde). The information uses above from MainActivity is on line 87.

Comment: probably yes, but did you run the create table query before this? can you post this query?

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLiteQueryBuilder is not a good solution if you have to retrieve a single table. It is made mostly for join queries.

If you need to do joins, have a look at [this link for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235516/using-sqlitequerybuilder-to-join-two-tables)

if you need to query a simple table, use the [query function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(myTable, myColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

And you are done

Comment: That was how i did to start with, the QueryBuilder came as part of the troubleshooting process. Before the line was `Cursor cursor = db.query(ActiveNotificationEntry.TABLE_NAME, CURSOR_COLUMNS,null,null,null,null,null,null);` But returning to this produces the same error.

Comment: @simwir this code must work, I'm using it in pretty much every project. you are doing something wrong in the way you call it. add in your question the async task doing it, in the error there is a problem in the "doInBackground()"

Comment: The thing is, it's not being called in an async tast. I have posted the files i think are relevant in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/simwir/33c222a1159de56a3395d46c5e7febde) The code snippet in the question above is from line 87 in MainActivity.java.

Comment: @simwir uhm, interesting. which line is exactly throwing the error?

Comment: Thats the thing, no line in my code is throwing the error, i don't think. I have stepped through the code with the debugger and it could complete it. Then when the emulator returned to normal operation the program crashes. I'm printing a onCreate start and end, and both gets printed before the app crashes.

Comment: @simwir it is because the problem is in the "doInBackground()" of your writeDemoDatabase

Comment: @simwir add also the ids in the content values

Comment: That "doInBackground()" is not run at this time, and commenting it out changes nothing. I also thought i got the ids from BaseColums extended in the "NotificationContract" file.

Comment: @simwir try debugging with breakpoints in all method you have in your mainactivity and check if anyone of them is called or if anyone of them is throwing anything. elseway I don't know

Comment: Have tried with break points and no luck. Thank you for your time, and i hope somebody else might have an idea to what the error could be.

Comment: @simwir welcome! if you want a last hint, create an empty activity, then add inside the oncreate ONLY the query. it must work, then add a row at a time and see when it stop working. If it doesn't work even with the empty activity, you have something wrong in your queries