# Android-Contacts and table joins not possible at-all?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-contacts, android-cursorloader

Currently i'm developing a dialer-app for the Android OS.

It shows callogs, contacts in ListViews.
A SearchView is used to search contacts by: surname, name, nickname and all it's numbers. If the search string represents a substring of the four key-kinds, the list shall be shrinked to the matching entries.

i'm using CursorAdapter and CursorLoader to fill the list.
This is very important for the sake of performance.
Till that point everything is working and absolute clear.

**Now the problem:**
I need to join 2-3 tables from default contacts db (contacts2.db),
in one single sql query.
So my app should not use it's own, private db.
But existing ContentProviders do not offer acces to more than one table.
--> PROBLEM!

Implementing my own [ContentProvider](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-Content-Providers), it is possible to do joins utilising the [SQLiteQueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235516/using-sqlitequerybuilder-to-join-two-tables).
But at a first glimpse that seems to work only for private databases.
When I try to directly access the contacts2.db, located in:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

I get following error:

```
Failed to open database '/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db'.
                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (Sqlite code 14): Could not open database, (OS error - 13:Permission denied)
```

Which is somehow expected, because every app has it's own storage, using an appropriate uid in the underlying linux filesystem.

So, how can I get read-acces to this database?
Can I request that db-object somehow from the android system or utilizing the Context object? Or can I gain those acces-rights somehow?

Would it be possible to use the same AUTHOTITY_NAME as the contacts App does?? Like this:

```
com.android.providers.contacts
```

- I'm not interested in joining columns using java code, that's UGLY, EXTREMELY SLOW, and I need a Cursor instead of a List or similar stuff anyway
- I don't need help in SQL
- I don't need help in how to implement android stuff

All you Android-Pros out there - is that possible at-all?
Or is the android api really that crappy?
Do i really have to "join" the needed info by using CursorJoiner and generate
somehow a Cursor object from the first one?

Thank you very much in advance, folks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You can't even assume that's the name of the contact db on a given device.  The only way to access the contacts db across all devices is to use the ContentResolver.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for `Match a Contact By Any Type of Data` as shown by the [Retrieving a List of Contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) official Android lesson.
You'll need to follow all 4 steps:

> Request Permission to Read the Provider
>   Match a Contact by Name and List the Results
>   Match a Contact By a Specific Type of Data
>   **Match a Contact By Any Type of Data**

Because the 4 step is based on the code created by the previous steps.

Basically, it's using a built-in search feature in Android's Contacts framework: [Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_FILTER_URI):

> Use Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI as the base URI, and append your
>   search string to it by calling Uri.withAppendedPath(). Using this URI
>   automatically triggers searching for any data type